# MySQL: Unknown column on 'on clause' for renamed column

Tags: mysql, left-join

Simplified version of my problem:

```
SELECT 
2 + 3 AS Test1
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
ON TableB.Column1 = Test1
```

It does not know about Test1 in join. Can I make the join to understand values from main field list such as Test1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option would be to use the same aggregate function in the `ON`:

```
SELECT 
   2 + 3 AS Test1
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
ON TableB.Column1 = 2 + 3
```

Or, you could use an inner `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT 2 + 3 AS Test1
   FROM TableA) MyTable
LEFT JOIN TableB
ON TableB.Column1 = MyTable.Test1
```

Comment: I haven't even considered moving the calculation to the JOIN but no reason why not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the first query like this:

```
SELECT * /*(or whatever you need here)*/
  FROM (SELECT 2 + 3 AS Test1 FROM TableA) a
  LEFT JOIN TableB
    ON TableB.Column1 = a.Test1
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you able to use variables:

```
  set @test1 = 1;
  SELECT 
  @test1 as Test1
  FROM category
  JOIN users on users.id = @test1
```